# How use a single color in trianglify.min.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, trianglify

I want to use only one color with the library trianglify.min.js

The library use colors random.

Comment: What have you already researched?

Answer (score 1):

`trianglify` library in Options [x_colors](https://github.com/qrohlf/trianglify/blob/master/Readme.md#x_colors), default is 'random'. Specify the color gradient used on the `x axis`.

Valid array values should specify the color stops in any CSS format (i.e. `['#000000', '#4CAFE8', '#FFFFFF'])`.

```
var pattern = Trianglify({
    cell_size: 75,
    variance: 0.75,
    x_colors: ['#fff','#28345A'],
    y_colors: 'match_x',
    palette: Trianglify.colorbrewer,
    color_space: 'rgb',
    color_function: false,
    stroke_width: 1.51,
    width: window.innerWidth-5,
    height: window.innerHeight-5,
    seed: 'd4hga',
    stroke_width: 1.51,
    color_function: null
});
document.body.appendChild(pattern.canvas())
```